# publishing php files from eclipse to apache htdocs

Tags: php, eclipse, apache

How can publish from Eclipse to Apache's htdocs on local?, I remember I was able to do this long time ago but forgot the process. Is there like a setting that i can do in Eclipse so that it publishes any file i add to the htdocs or if I modify it?. Initially I copied the whole folder from workspace and put it in htdocs.. and it runs but now any change I make in eclipse does not get publish.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming your htdocs folder is stored locally. If that is the case, then the easiest route would be to simply create a new workspace whose root directory will actually **be** the htdocs folder.

In this case:

1. Go to: File > Switch Workspace > Other.
2. Click browse and look for your htdocs folder and select it.

Now when you create a new project, your htdocs folder should be the default location in which to create the new project.

Comment: Simple and effective! You just delivered me from half a day's madness!

Comment: thsi has nothing to do with the initial post. I have been looking for the same thing. Quite frankly making the document root the workspace is a bad practice. Simply PDT doesn't seem to know how to publish to a different folder of the same filesystem

Comment: @blacksensei I disagree about that being bad practice, but agree that PDT doesn't know how to do much.  Which is yet another reason why, after 6 or 7 years of using it, I stopped using Eclipse/ZendStudio and I'm much, much, _much_ happier with PHPStorm. :)

Comment: what if i'm using git :/ ?

Comment: @Moatez I believe, current versions of eclipse have "Create Project From Git Repository" or something like that.  I stopped using eclipse about two years ago, so I don't remember exactly.  I now use JetBrains, it's much better for me.  :)  Best of luck!