# Navigate XAMPP htdocs Files using PHP - Eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, wordpress, xampp

I'm just starting with wordpress tutorials and I am not familiar in using Eclipse-PHP. It seems like eclipse is easier than notepad++ as editor so that i want to learn how to use eclipse editor.

My problem is its quite pain in the ass figuring out how to just simply navigate my files Using Eclipse. How can I navigate my XAMPP files using PHP-Eclipse.

The picture below shows the expected output on navigator window:

[image]

I'll use this to auto update my htdocs files in my localhost server in xampp.

I see the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110063/publishing-php-files-from-eclipse-to-apache-htdocs) which gives the instruction to switch workplace but i don't get how to browse the files with the categories below:

[image]

Please help me with this and i'm about an hour exploring php eclipse.

Your help will be greatly appreciated for a starter like me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Eclipse you create "projects" as opposed to browsing the entire filesystem. So in this case let say you had a blog to work on that you have in `htdocs/theblog.com`.

You would right click on the project explorer window and "Create new project" then choose the appropriate project type - in this case PHP. Then you would select the option that says use an existing location and browse in typical fashion to `htdocs/theblog.com`. Then proceed through the rest of the wizard. and finish.

Eclipse will then index the project and run a series of validators and stuff... essentially "building" the project. After that you will see the project in the project explorer pane. You can repeat this for all your individual projects.

Like wise you can close and open projects to keep them out of the way when youre working on one or another.

Comment: Thanks prodigitalson. It really helped me a lot.